# How to install apps from inside my app like play store

Tags: java, android, installation, apk

I want to install apps on the device using my app.

Like I have an app named "ABC" and from inside that on click of a button. I also searched GitHub for this type of implementation. Luckily I found one on [this link](https://github.com/Piashsarker/AndroidAppUpdateLibrary).

But when it comes to adding code in manifest ([Click here to find out the part I am mentioning about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3TH4c.png)), it shows an error like this ([check this error out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KS8Tv.png)).

What do I do because I really need to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is because you're using AndroidX in your application

Your provider code should look like so

```
<manifest>
    ...
    <application>
        ...
        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.mydomain.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            ...
        </provider>
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: You should try it out and mark it as the accepted answer if it works

Comment: it is not giving error but I am unable to install app apk. The error is unable to find provider in manifest.Then app crashes.

Comment: That's probably because the library doesn't have AndroidX support maybe then, however the task you want to do is pretty easy

Comment: Then what do i do.

Comment: Download the app using `DownloadManager` and then install it using `PackageInstaller`, you may read the docs for both the mentioned class. You can check [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testdpc/blob/5b8297e9d51983a774ba3391e28a6aa35ca3f062/app/src/main/java/com/afwsamples/testdpc/cosu/CosuUtils.java) for an example